# Border radius css issue with percent

Tags: css, html

I've tried to make rounded border but couldn't.

This is the image I want to implement.

Disregard about background.

[image]

This is the css code I've done.

```
padding: 10px 25px;
background: #777777;
border-radius:50% 50%;
```

But the result is as follows.

[image]

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: replace your `50% 50%` with a smooth `1em` and voila.

Comment: don't work with % but try em or pixels

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vc3pwjk9/ chill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible duplicate comment suggests the problem but does not give any solution.

And using 1em will set border radius equal to the base font-size applied to the element.

I would suggest you to give values of 5-6 ems. In this case it will go till any shortest side reaches 50% and then will become ineffective.

```css
.btn {
  border: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 6em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 4</button>
```